# emacs, nrepl, M-. (nrepl-jump): Searching for program: permission denied, unzip

Tags: emacs, clojure, file-permissions, nrepl

UPD: My OS is Win7 64 bit

I'm getting the following error when trying to jump to symbol's definition with M-.

```
Searching for program: permission denied, unzip
```

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=40&hl=en&q=%22Searching+for+program+permission+denied%2C+unzip%22&oq=%22Searching+for+program+permission+denied%2C+unzip%22&gs_l=serp.3...1420.2124.0.2371.2.2.0.0.0.0.85.128.2.2.0....0...1c.1.27.serp..2.0.0.zlppdWcDGDU) doesn't help me much with that issue. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

here is the part of my config related to clojure:

```
;; clojure

(require 'clojure-mode)

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq buffer-save-without-query t)))

;;command to align let statements
;;To use: M-x align-cljlet
(require 'align-cljlet)

(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.cljs$" . clojure-mode))
                              auto-mode-alist))

(dolist (x '(scheme emacs-lisp lisp clojure))
  (add-hook (intern (concat (symbol-name x) "-mode-hook")) 'rainbow-delimiters-mode))


;; nrepl

(require 'nrepl )

(defun live-windows-hide-eol ()
 "Do not show ^M in files containing mixed UNIX and DOS line endings."
 (interactive)
 (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
 (aset buffer-display-table ?\^M []))


(when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'live-windows-hide-eol ))

(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (nrepl-turn-on-eldoc-mode)))

(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (nrepl-turn-on-eldoc-mode)))


(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces nil)
(setq nrepl-popup-stacktraces-in-repl nil)
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*nrepl*")

;;Auto Complete
(require 'ac-nrepl )
(add-hook 'nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'nrepl-interaction-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)
(add-hook 'clojure-nrepl-mode-hook 'ac-nrepl-setup)

(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'nrepl-mode))

;; specify the print length to be 100 to stop infinite sequences killing things.
(defun live-nrepl-set-print-length ()
  (nrepl-send-string-sync "(set! *print-length* 100)" "clojure.core"))

(add-hook 'nrepl-connected-hook 'live-nrepl-set-print-length)

;;; Windows M-. navigation fix
;(defun nrepl-jump-to-def (var)
;  "Jump to the definition of the var at point."
;  (let ((form (format "((clojure.core/juxt
;                         (comp (fn [s] (if (clojure.core/re-find #\"[Ww]indows\" (System/getProperty \"os.name\"))
;                                           (.replace s \"file:/\" \"file:\")
;                                           s))
;                               clojure.core/str
;                               clojure.java.io/resource :file)
;                         (comp clojure.core/str clojure.java.io/file :file) :line)
;                        (clojure.core/meta (clojure.core/ns-resolve '%s '%s)))"
;                      (nrepl-current-ns) var)))
;    (nrepl-send-string form
;                       (nrepl-jump-to-def-handler (current-buffer))
;                       (nrepl-current-ns)
;                       (nrepl-current-tooling-session))))

(setq nrepl-port "4555")
```

Comment: Specify the system. Make sure that unzip is fine (`which unzip`). Also that you have permissions for the
clojure jar( mine is in `~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you don't have `unzip` installed.

If you have 7-Zip, add its directory under "Program Files" to your PATH environment variable. When I did that and restarted Emacs, it automatically recognized it as `unzip` alternative and configured itself correctly (i.e. the variable `archive-zip-extract` was set to `("7z" "x" "-so")`).

Ideally, it should be possible to use Java's own `jar` program for this, but apparently it doesn't support extracting individual files to stdout which is the way Emacs' arc-mode works.